# SwiftUI - How can handle that multiple requests? There is 2 request how can I manage it?

Tags: swift, multithreading

Im creating an app related about images and also implemented Adapty in app purchase framework.
Im using for images firebase, and sending a request on appear in app, and also I have a paywall which image is premium.
When I make a purchase quickly -I mean before the loading selected image- payment pop-up re initialize my main view, and shows the payment
If going after loading images it works as expected

I would like to make same behavior, no need to waiting loading image for purchases.
Im thinking its releated about threads but I can not solved yet :(

That's how it looks like if make a purchase without loading
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idSD6.jpg)
that's the expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmlyo.jpg)